# Ошибка добавления элементов методом append

Tags: jquery

Ничего не пойму. создаю несколько элементов динамически с помощью append 
если пишу

```
$('#configuration').append('< div>блаблабла</div>');   – то все нормально, но если 
$('#configuration').append('< input type=hidden..../>');  – зависает и ничего не происходит.
```

Попытка создать любой input терпит поражение. что это может быть? Любые тэги создает, а инпат вообще не хочет

Comment: `type="hidden"` про кавычки не забываем [пруф](http://jsfiddle.net/ux4k3/)

Comment: не помогает.
даже пишу
$('#configuration').append('<input/>');  - все равно ругается

Comment: "ругается"? а подробнее?

Comment: да ничего не пишет. просто при клике (функция срабатывает от onclick) форма как-бы замерзает и больше ничего с ней не сделаешь.

Comment: а firebug ?

Comment: желательно код всего обработчика глянуть..

Answer (score 0):

Все работает

```js
$('#configuration').append('<input type="text"/>');
$('#configuration').append('<input type="hidden" name="hidden-input"/>')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="configuration"></div>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]